# Submit an array via jquery / js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how can i submit an array to new page via JS / JQUERY.
$.ajax and $.post return data back to the same page,but i need to send an array into new PHP page,exactly same as submitting a form .

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: Please show some code, we will check what you have tried still.

Comment: I don not  ask to write the code, my problem is , when we use $.ajax and $.post in our code , Ajax return back data in same page. is there any way which we submit an array to new PHP page ?

Comment: What do you mean by "submit an array to new PHP page"? Do you want request from page A and response in page B? Clarify.

Comment: @Nirjhar Lo: yes exactly , but via js or jquery
something like document.createElement('form1') and add array into it then submit

Comment: I don't think it's possible using js in a page. You can make request to other files when your request is being processed in the server. e.g. you send request from page A with some info so that when the server processes the info it calls in page B and sends some info. Anyway you need to make 2 requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to generated a java script array/object using your form data.
Have a look :)

```
    <script>
$("#yourFormIdname").submit(function(){
    var first_name=$("#yourFirstNamefieldId").val();
    var last_name=$("#yourLastNamefieldId").val();
    var formData={first_name:first_name,last_name:last_name};
    $.ajax({
        url:"Give your target url",
        type:"POST",
        data:{formData:formData}
        })

})
</script>
```

In your target PHP page

```
$data=$_POST['formData']
print_r($data);
```

Comment: it will return back respond to the same page, i want to reload target page .
exactly same as submitting the form

Comment: Do u stay in target page ?

Comment: no, i want to reload in target page, same as Submit a form.
but the issue is, i have a multi dimensional array and want to post it in target page (submit it).
i mean synchronous not asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

you can use name field as array like

```
name="name[]"
```

so that you will get as array.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use asynchronous methods for that ($.ajax, $.post, $.get). Instead of that you should $('#form').submit() the real HTML-form, having action attribute. If you'll use names like 'name="name[]"' you can submit arrays.

Comment: how about generate dynamic form?
let say i use document.createElement('form') , how can i add an array into it and submit it?

Comment: var form = $('body').append('<form action="URL" method="post">');

$(form).append('<input name="name[]" value="1">');

$(form).append('<input name="name[]" value="2">');
$(form).append('<input name="name[]" value="3">');
$(form).submit();

Comment: the issue is , you are adding dynamically input, i have multi dimensional array in a variable and want to submit it

Comment: You should encode your array as json (https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), put the result to a hidden field and submit the form. Then on the server side you could decodeJson and you'll get your array.

Comment: serializeArray also make array from object , i already have an array and wanna submit it to the target page

Comment: Try $('#your_hidden_field').val( JSON.stringify( your_array) ); then submit form.

Comment: yes it can be done, to pass json in Hidden field and submit the form.
Thanks